# Auto-completing "Create Polygon Tool" Maya

Tags: python, python-2.7, polygon, maya, pymel

I'm trying to figure out a way to create an auto-completing "Create Polygon Tool" in Maya, in Python. It's so when you build geometry, it will select the previous geometry, and the current one you made, and run a line of commands.

I've run into a snag, though, in which the Create Poly tool actually doesn't let you exit its command.

Would anyone know a way around this?

Here's a snip-bit of my code:

```
from pymel.core import *
def codeToExecute():
    #lists, combines, does a few other things like deleting history
polyCreateFaceCtx('newCtx',mp=4)
setToolTo('newCtx')                      #allows you to create a polygon
maya.mel.eval('CompleteCurrentTool')     #need this to stop it from continuing its loop
geo=ls(sl=True)
codeToExecute()
```

However, since it's run together, it sets the tool to create a polygon and quits it automatically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force exit the context with

```
cmds.setToolTo('selectSuperContext')
```

which will switch you to the select tool and complete the poly tool.  However that's not going to work as you've laid it out here, I think: you'll swicth to the tool and immediately switch out without waiting for the user to create stuff.

You might have an easier time setting up a one-time scriptJob that looks for new object creation, which will run when the user exits the command on their own:

```
def do_something(*_):
    print cmds.ls(sl=True)

cmds.scriptJob(e=('DagObjectCreated', do_something), runOnce =True)
cmds.polyCreateFaceCtx('newCtx',mp=4)
cmds.setToolTo('newCtx')
```

That will fire the scriptJob when the user completes the tool on their own.

Comment: I like that, I'll test out the scriptjob. I haven't ever used that function before and was hoping to use it at a time like this, but wasn't sure how.